# Find the transformation matrix $A$ of a random vector $X $such that $Y = XA^T$ has uncorrelated components.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve this problem. I need to find matrix A such that transformed vector's components are uncorrelated.

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the notation (for simplicity) to column vectors $X_{2\times1}$ and $Y_{2\times1}$, the equation is written as $Y=AX$.

Eigenvalue decomposition of $C_n$ is 
$$C_n=QDQ^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\ 
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\ 
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $Q^T=Q^{-1}$.

To decorrelate $Y$ elements, we need to have $$\mathsf{E}(YY^T)=\Lambda$$
where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix.

Choosing $A=Q^T$ yields $Y=Q^TX$ and

$$\mathsf{E}(YY^T)=\mathsf{E}(Q^TXX^TQ)=Q^T\mathsf{E}(XX^T)Q=Q^{-1}C_nQ=Q^{-1}(QDQ^{-1})Q=D$$
Hence, $\Lambda=D$, and the decorrelating transform is 
$$Y=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\ 
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}X$$